# How to retain Fragment inside of a programmatically added ViewGroup during a configuration change

Tags: android, android-fragments

Let's say that

**1)** I have this code that adds a new `Fragment` on a specific user interaction:

```
ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.packetFragmentContainer);
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
linearLayout.setId(View.generateViewId());
vg.addView(linearLayout);
String fragmentTag = "FRAGMENT_" + linearLayout.getId();
PacketEditorFragment fragment =
            (PacketEditorFragment) 
             getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag);

if(fragment == null) {
    Log.d(TAG, "No fragment for tag '" + fragmentTag + "'- creating a new fragment");
    fragment = PacketEditorFragment.newInstance();
    fragment.setRetainInstance(true);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
          .add(linearLayout.getId(), fragment, fragmentTag)
          .commit();
} else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Fragment already in this world");
}
```

**How can I restore the ViewGroups containing the `Fragments` (and the Fragment views) when the user rotates the device?**

Currently, I save the IDs of the `LinearLayout` I create (and then all the `fragmentTag`) during the `onSaveInstanceState` and create the same `LinearLayout` elements during `onCreate` or `onRestoreInstance` state.

However, every time I rotate the device one `Fragment` disappears, specifically the first one (from the second on they are reinstated).